# Program not printing parts into output file C++

Tags: c++, file-io, output

I have been trying to solve this for a while now and it seems that everything I try has made it worse. I am designing a program which reads an input file, does calculations, and prints to an output file. (Its a grade calculator of sorts) Right now I am just trying to get it to display the name and ID number in the output for each line in the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

float printRecord ( char name[20], char Id[20], ostream& outfile)
{
outfile << name << " " << Id << endl;
return 0;
}

int main()
{
ofstream outfile;
ifstream infile; 

std::string line;

char file_nameI[21], file_nameO[21], name[20], Id[20];

float  hworkgrade, grade1;
int deductions;

cout << "Please enter name of input file:  ";
cin >> file_nameI;
infile.open(file_nameI);
if ( !infile)
{
  cout << "Could not open input file \n";
  return 0;
}

cout << "Please enter name of output file:  ";
cin >> file_nameO;
infile.open(file_nameO);
if ( !outfile)
{
  cout << "Could not open output file \n";
  return 0;
}

  while (getline (infile, line))
  {
  istringstream iss(line);
  iss >> name >> Id;
  cout<< name << " " << Id;
  printRecord(name, Id, outfile);
  cin.ignore();
  }

  return 0;

  }
```

Here is the input

```
Truman, Tod 12388671 100 100 100 
Seger,John 67894 100 100 100 100
Victoire,Susan 938442 0 0 0 
Kodak,James 554668 101 100 100
Frence,Lauren 602983 -1 100 100
Hanz, Franz 58027201 100 100 100
Laufeson,Loki 7920100 34 59 24
```

Here is the output:

```
 12388671
Seger,John 67894
Victoire,Susan 938442
Kodak,James 554668
Frence,Lauren 602983
 58027201
Laufeson,Loki 7920100
```

It skips over the first and sixth name.

I have tried changing the variables to string variables, changing the order of the loop, setting the name to two variable (first and last)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using `std::string` as opposed to `char XYZ[xx]`?

Comment: close your file after writing to it.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that for those two input lines, you have a space between the names.

Compare

```
Truman, Tod 12388671 100 100 100 
Seger,John 67894 100 100 100 100
```

Since `istringstream::operator>>` reads up until a space it will stop at that space when reading the first string and will receive the second part of the name in the second string instead of the number.

The solution make your data consistent or allow for the presence or absence of the space when parsing the lines.

You have another typo which would render your example code here unusable. You never open the output file. You open the input file twice !!

`infile.open(file_nameO);` => `outfile.open(file_nameO);`

Some fixed up code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printRecord ( const string& name, const string& Id, ostream& outfile) {
    outfile << name << " " << Id << endl; }

int main() {
    string line;
    string file_nameI, file_nameO;

    cout << "Please enter name of input file:  ";
    //cin >> file_nameI;
    file_nameI = "grades.txt";
    cout << file_nameI << '\n';
    ifstream infile(file_nameI.c_str());
    if ( !infile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter name of output file:  ";
    //cin >> file_nameO;
    file_nameO = "gradesout.txt";
    cout << file_nameO << '\n';

    ofstream outfile(file_nameO.c_str());
    if ( !outfile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open output file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline (infile, line))
    {
        string name, id;
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> name >> id;
        cout << name << " " << id;
        printRecord(name, id, outfile);
        cin.ignore();
    } }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Also the reason for the inconsistency in the input is because I originally had my name there, and when I posted it on here I obviously changed it but I didn't double check. However I added your other suggestion and now my code is working flawlessly!